# Would you be willing to give me feedback on my procedural program?

Tags: c++

Hi programming community, I was wondering if any of you would be kind enough to give me feedback on my c++ procedural program? I'm new to programming so any feedback on how perhaps I could make my code more efficient would be greatly appreciated. For example, have I made good use of DO / WHILE loops or is there a better way? Based on what you see, would you be kind enough to give it a rating out of 10. Thank you to anyone who bothers or cares to do so!

```
//  Created by George Austin Bradley on 19/11/2019.
//  Copyright © 2019 George Austin Bradley. All rights reserved.


#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//1. This displays the car menu items.
void display_menu()
{
    cout << "\nMENU";
    cout << "\n1. Blue Nissan Skyline";
    cout << "\n2. Red Mini";
    cout << "\n3. Black Land Rover";
    cout << "\n";
}

//This procedure proccesses the user's selection and all information regarding price and name of car are then transferred to transaction variables.
void selectedCar(double &dCostOfChosenCar, string &sNameOfChosenCar)
{
    int iSelectionFromMenu = 0;
    double dCar1 = 1000, dCar2 = 3000, dCar3 = 4000;
    string sCar1 = "Blue Nissan Skyline", sCar2 = "Red Mini", sCar3 = "Black Land Rover";

    do{
        display_menu();
        cout << "\nChoose a car that you'd wish to buy from the menu (1 - 3): ";
        cin >> iSelectionFromMenu;
        if(iSelectionFromMenu == 1)
        {
            sNameOfChosenCar = sCar1;
            dCostOfChosenCar = dCar1;
        }
        else if (iSelectionFromMenu == 2){
            sNameOfChosenCar = sCar2;
            dCostOfChosenCar = dCar2;
        }
        else if (iSelectionFromMenu == 3)
        {
            sNameOfChosenCar = sCar3;
            dCostOfChosenCar = dCar3;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nPlease enter valid number!";
        }
    }while(iSelectionFromMenu < 0 || iSelectionFromMenu > 3);
}
//This procedure gets from the user their preferred finance plan through their input.
void FinanceLength(int &iFinanceLength)
{
    do{
        cout << "\nHow long do you wish for your finance plan to last? (1 - 4 years): ";
        cin >> iFinanceLength;
        if (iFinanceLength < 0 || iFinanceLength > 4)
        {
            cout << "\nOops, try again! Please enter between 1 - 4!";
        }
    }while(iFinanceLength < 0 || iFinanceLength > 4);
}

//This procedure gets the user's deposit.
void DepositMoney(double &dDepositAmount, double dCostOfChosenCar)
{
    do{
        cout << "\nEnter deposit amount (minimum £500 accepted): £";
        cin >> dDepositAmount;
        if (dDepositAmount < 500)
        {
            cout << "\nTry again! Deposit an amount greater than or equal to £500.";
        }
    }while(dDepositAmount < 500);
}

//This function calculates the amount of money the user has to pay after deposit, added tax and charge percentage of 10%
double TotalLeftToPay(double iFinanceLength, double dDepositAmount, double dCostOfChosenCar)
{
    double dChargePercentage = 0.10;
    double dTotalLeftToPay = dCostOfChosenCar + (dCostOfChosenCar * dChargePercentage) - dDepositAmount + 135;
    return dTotalLeftToPay;
}

//This calculates monthly payments.
double MonthlyPayments(double dTotalLeftToPay, int iFinanceLength)
{
    double dMonthlyPayments = (dTotalLeftToPay / iFinanceLength) / 12;
    return dMonthlyPayments;
}
//This asks the user whether they'd like to restart the application.
void RestartOptions(char &cOption, bool *bExit)
{
    do{
        cout << "\nDo you wish to restart your application? (y/n): ";
        cin >> cOption;
        if (cOption == 'Y' || cOption == 'y')
        {
            *bExit = false;
        }
        else if (cOption == 'N' || cOption == 'n')
        {
            *bExit = true;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Sorry, that's an invalid input, please try again!";
        }
    }while(cOption != 'y' && cOption != 'Y' && cOption != 'n' && cOption != 'N');
}

//This string function returns either year or years (plural)
string YearOrYears(int iFinanceLength)
{
    if (iFinanceLength > 1)
    {
        return "years";
    }
    else
    {
        return "year";
    }
}

//This displays receipt of the user's transaction.
void Receipt(string &sUserName, string &sNameOfChosenCar, int &iFinanceLength, double &dDepositAmount, double &dCostOfChosenCar, char cOption, bool *bExit)
{
    cout << "\nHi, " << sUserName << ". ";
    cout << "\nYou have chosen " << sNameOfChosenCar << ".";
    cout << "\nYour finance plan timescale is " << iFinanceLength << " " << YearOrYears(iFinanceLength) << ".";
    cout << "\nYou've deposited £" << dDepositAmount << ".";
    double dTotalLeftToPay = TotalLeftToPay(iFinanceLength, dDepositAmount, dCostOfChosenCar);
    cout << "\nTotal left to pay: £" << dTotalLeftToPay;
    double dMonthlyPayments = MonthlyPayments(dTotalLeftToPay, iFinanceLength);
    cout << "\nMonthly Payments: £" << dMonthlyPayments;
    RestartOptions(cOption, bExit);
}

//This asks the user whether they're happy with the options of they've chosen.
void AcceptDeclineOptions(string &sUserName, string &sNameOfChosenCar, int &iFinanceLength, double &dDepositAmount, double &dCostOfChosenCar, bool *bExit)
{
    char cOption = 0;

    do
    {
        cout << "\nDo you agree with the options you've chosen? (y/n): ";
        cin >> cOption;

        if (cOption == 'Y' || cOption == 'y' || cOption == 'N' || cOption == 'n')
        {
            if (cOption == 'Y' || cOption == 'y')
            {
                Receipt(sUserName, sNameOfChosenCar, iFinanceLength, dDepositAmount, dCostOfChosenCar, cOption, bExit);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nSorry, that's not a valid command.";
        }
    }while(cOption != 'y' && cOption != 'Y' && cOption != 'n' && cOption != 'N');
}


int main()
{
    bool *bExit = new bool;
    string sNameOfChosenCar = "";
    double dCostOfChosenCar = 0;
    int iFinanceLength = 0;
    double dDepositAmount = 0;
    *bExit = false;

    do{
        cout << "Welcome!";
        string sUserName = "";
        cout << "\nEnter your name: ";
        cin >> sUserName;

        selectedCar(dCostOfChosenCar, sNameOfChosenCar);
        FinanceLength(iFinanceLength);
        DepositMoney(dDepositAmount, dCostOfChosenCar);
        AcceptDeclineOptions(sUserName, sNameOfChosenCar, iFinanceLength,dDepositAmount, dCostOfChosenCar, bExit);

    }while(*bExit == false);

    delete bExit;
}
```

Comment: I believe your question would be much more suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `bool *bExit = new bool;` -- Why?  `bool bExit;` is all you need.

Comment: For some reason I tried that before but it just didn't seem to work i.e. it wouldn't exit the program in the main(). I thought I'd use a pointer and it then worked. I've tried it again and now it works, I must have been doing something wrong before. Thanks for the help!

Comment: stackoverflow.com is not for providing "feedback". This is off-topic. codereview would be more appropriate for this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be more suited to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: "I must have been doing something wrong before.": You should understand the root cause of your problem. Just because it looked like it behaved properly doesn't necessarily mean it actually did...

Comment: @GeorgeAustinBradley -- Probably the variable was not initialized, and you were using it in an uninitialized state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm typing this on a phone and not a compiler, I would like to apologies for any syntax errors.

Pros:

- You have the basics of formatting and structure down.
- Your code is clean and easy to read.(Can not stress how important that is)
- Your variable naming is also good. By that I mean the type prefix (s)String, (d)Double etc...

Cons:

- Your limited use of language features, such as classes, arrays and logic statements (inexperience, it will ware off)

You are well on your way.
May I suggest you create a class for your car objects.
[Here is a great tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/)

```
class cCar{
    private:
        string _sName;
        double _dPrice;
    public:
        cCar(string s, double d){
            _sName = s;
            _dPrice = d;
        }
    string getName(){return _sName;}
    double getPrice(){return _dPrice;}
}

std::vector<cCar> car_list; //create a dynamic array of car objects
```

This will make it easier to switch to using an array or `std::vector` to store all your cars in. For example, your display function could be altered like so, This will print all cars in your list. making it easier to add new models. [Here is more information about using vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

```
void display_menu()
{
    cout << "\nMENU";
    for( i=0; i!=car_list.size(); ++i)
        cout << "\n" << i << ". " << car_list[i].getName()
    cout << "\n";
}
```

The next function really shows a car 'class' and 'vector' would be better. You have hard coded each price and description for each car, into their own variable. So if you wanted to add more cars, you have to add more variables. This would become repetitive.

```
void selectedCar(double &dCostOfChosenCar, string &sNameOfChosenCar)
{
    int iSelectionFromMenu = -1;
    do{
        display_menu();
        cout << "\nChoose a car that you'd wish to buy from the menu (1 - " 
             << car_list.size() << "): ";
        cin >> iSelectionFromMenu;
        if(iSelectionFromMenu >= 0 && iSelectionFromMenu < car_list.size())
        {
            sNameOfChosenCar = car_list[iSelectionFromMenu].getName();
            dCostOfChosenCar = car_list[iSelectionFromMenu].getPrice();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nPlease enter valid number!";
            iSelectionFromMenu = -1
        }
    }while(iSelectionFromMenu  == -1);
}
```

The Next functions looks good

```
void FinanceLength(int &iFinanceLength)
void DepositMoney(double &dDepositAmount, double dCostOfChosenCar)
double TotalLeftToPay(double iFinanceLength, double dDepositAmount, double dCostOfChosenCar)
double MonthlyPayments(double dTotalLeftToPay, int iFinanceLength)
```

Your next function takes user input and compares it both Upper and Lower case.
This looks like a great time to introduce the [`switch` and `continue` statements](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/)

```
void RestartOptions(char &cOption, bool *bExit)
{
    do{
        cout << "\nDo you wish to restart your application? (y/n): ";
        cin >> cOption;
        switch(cOption){
            case 'Y':
            case 'y':
                *bExit = false;
                break;
            case 'N':
            case 'n':
                *bExit = true;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Sorry, that's an invalid input, please try again!";
                continue; //keeps us in the do, while loop
        }
        break; //exits loop
    }while(1);
}
```

There is an easier way to do this, by using `toLower()` or `std::transform` but that's another post

This next function can be simplified by using ... I don't have a clue what its name is but its a cool little statement.

```
//This string function returns either year or years (plural)
string YearOrYears(int iFinanceLength)
{
    return (iFinanceLength > 1)? "years" : "year"
}
```

In 'void AcceptDeclineOptions()' the switch statement would work great.

Now you a few extra steps in main(). First put all the cars to 'car_list'

```
int main()
{
    car_list.append(cCar("Blue Nissan Skyline", 1000));
    car_list.append(cCar("Red Mini", 3000));
    car_list.append(cCar("Black Land Rover", 4000));

    bool bExit = false;
    string sNameOfChosenCar = "";
    double dCostOfChosenCar = 0;
    int iFinanceLength = 0;
    double dDepositAmount = 0;

    do{
        cout << "Welcome!";
        string sUserName = "";
        cout << "\nEnter your name: ";
        cin >> sUserName;

        selectedCar(dCostOfChosenCar, sNameOfChosenCar);
        FinanceLength(iFinanceLength);
        DepositMoney(dDepositAmount, dCostOfChosenCar);
        AcceptDeclineOptions(sUserName, sNameOfChosenCar, iFinanceLength,dDepositAmount, dCostOfChosenCar, bExit);

    }while(!bExit);
}
```

Comment: Hi Ron, I originally started using the switch statement but had no clue how to continue the loop when it reached its default so I switched (no pun intended) to the IF statements. I completely forgot / didn’t know about the “continue” statement. Thanks very much for simplifying and adding to the efficiency of the code, as well as showing me another way of writing an if statement. 

I’m going to look further into classes! I really appreciate your feedback, I’ve learned a ton!

Comment: Just a question, where you use the word “append”, is that referring to push_back?

Comment: Yes it is, I have been doing a lot of python lately. sorry about that